# Skip xml "premature end of data" error

Tags: php, xml, handler

I have a faulty xml feed. It cuts off some of the nodes, they are broken and I get the following errors messages -

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Premature end of data in tag 

hotelDescription line 30760 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/source.xml, line: 30760 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/file.php on line 22

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Premature end of data in tag product line 30741 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/source.xml, line: 30760 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/file.php on line 22

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Premature end of data in tag products line 2 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/source.xml, line: 30760 in /srv/disk9/561574/www/file.php on line 22
0
```

I have setup an error handler but I'm not sure how to, or if it is even possible, to ignore an element if it causes an error?

```
/* load the file on the DOM*/
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($filename);

if (!$dom->load($filename)) {
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        // handle errors here

    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered after much research this doesn't seem possible to skip broken elements.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13609656/1122187

In my situation, the feed breaks at the end, so I used XMLreader to pull through only a certain amount, using a limit, so it doesn't reach the last broken elements.

```
while ($reader->read()) 
{
    if (($reader->name == $element1  || $reader->name == $element2) && $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT)
    {
    $name = $reader->name;
        if ($i == $limit) break;
        while ($reader->read())
        {
            if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT
                || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA
                || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::WHITESPACE
                || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE)
            {
                $product[$i][$name] = $reader->value;
            }
            else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == $element1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == $element2)
            {
                break;
            }



         }

         if($name == $element2)
    $i++;

    }
}
$reader->close();
```

code above is credit to Jose Vega from this link - [PHP xmlreader to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349105/php-xmlreader-to-array)