# PHP XmlReader - Read error while parsing

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

To read XML files use:

```
$XMLFile = new XMLReader();

if($XMLFile->open('file.xml') === TRUE){                            

    while($XMLFile->read()) {

        //Do something

    }

    $XMLFile->close();

}
```

If I will find in xml file sample string:

```
!+_)(*&^%$#@!~}|"?,../;'\[]=-
```

Critical error is displayed and the parsing is terminated:

```
Warning: XMLReader::read() [xmlreader.read]: file.xml:16: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in test.php on line 841
Warning: XMLReader::read() [xmlreader.read]: An Error Occured while reading in test.php on line 841
```

In this case, I would like to handle the error and delete the xml file. Someone may know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to deal with the error-condition you have there. But first of all I think you should know that `XMLReader` is based on `libxml` and [`libxml` offers various functions](http://php.net/ref.libxml) and even the [`LibXMLError` object](http://php.net/LibXMLError) for the error-handling:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open($file)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open file.');
}

while ($reader->read()) {
    //Do something
}

if (libxml_get_last_error()) {
    // There was an error reading the file
    unlink($file);
}
```

The error information exemplary is:

```
LibXMLError Object
(
    [level] => 3
    [code] => 68
    [column] => 12
    [message] => xmlParseEntityRef: no name

    [file] => /path/to/file.xml
    [line] => 2
)
```

For this exemplary XML file:

```
<root>
    !+_)(*&^%$#@!~}|"?,../;'\[]=-
</root>
```

If you want to reduce the error output, you can make use of something called *internal errors* in libxml.

See as well:

- [XMLReader encoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/819414/367456)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The problem is that your XML is invalid. You are not supposed to have special chars in XML (i.e. & should be converted to & during XML file generation).

For more info, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158922/1719108) similar problem.

You basically have two options:

1. You can fix the file before parsing (for example using regex)
2. You can fix the code that generates XML in the first place

Answer (score -2):

Use [XMLReader::isValid()](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.isvalid.php).

```
<?php $xml = XMLReader->open('file.xml');

// You have to use this:
$xml->setParserProperty(XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);

var_dump($xml->isValid());
?>
```

Comment: now i have new error: validity error : Validation failed: no DTD found !

Comment: For XML, there is "valid" and "well-formed". For well-formed, the general syntax must be correct (matching tags, proper formatting). For valid, it must be well-formed and must adhere to the DTD. Without DTD, it can only be well-formed, but never valid.

Comment: The other comments aside, `XMLReader->open` is not valid. You need to create an instance of `XMLReader` first (in case anyone else was hoping this might have been shorthand for opening a XML file).